# Print the contents of a slice of struct

Tags: go, struct, printing, slice

Apologies if this is wrong to begin with. I am attempting to learn Golang, and am working through various concepts. I am pretty sure I am confusing something here... I am trying to write a simple program that creates a struct called 'person' which accepts firstname, lastname, and age. I want a user to be able to specify the number of people they will be entering into a slice of struct person, then iterate through the number of people entered, taking the input and storing it in the slice of person. Then, I want to be able to print one of those 'person' to terminal, for instance the 6th one (assuming that many were entered). Here is what I have so far:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var people int

    type person struct {
        firstName string
        lastName  string
        age       int
    }

    listOfPeople := make([]person, 10)

    fmt.Println("Please enter the number of users you would like to   create:")
    fmt.Scan(&people)

    for i := 0; i < people; i++ {
        var a, b string
        var c int
        fmt.Println("Please enter a person's information: ")
        fmt.Print("First Name: ")
        fmt.Scan(&a)
        fmt.Print("Last Name: ")
        fmt.Scan(&b)
        fmt.Print("Age: ")
        fmt.Scan(&c)
        listOfPeople = append(listOfPeople, person{a, b, c})
    }
    //Print the contents of listOfPeople
}
```

Where the code comment "print the contents of listOfPeople is where I would like to be able to print a 'person'. I have tried a couple of things but nothing prints or compilation fails. Without attempting to print out a person from listOfPeople the code compiles and runs. I know I am missing something here. Any help is appreciated. I realize this code is likely not optimized or there may be a simpler way of doing it, so if there is please feel free to correct me. 
Thank you

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: You do `listOfPeople := make([]person, 10)`, then later `listOfPeople = append(listOfPeople, person{a, b, c})`. If you're using `append`, you should use the 3-arg form of `make` to set the capacity of the slice to 10 and the length to 0, else you'll have 10 people if you enter 0, 11 people if you enter 1, etc. That might be your problem, or one of them at least.

Comment: This combined with @mkopriva's answer allowed me to fix the problem. I changed listOfPeople := make([]person, 10) to listOfPeople := make([]person, 0, 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appending to a slice of already allocated 10 people, so you may think that the first person you appended is on the 0th index but it's actually be on the 10th.

https://play.golang.org/p/bPXsdWk9sa

What you probably want is something like this

https://play.golang.org/p/kcfzJ4M0Wp

Comment: Hey, Thanks that illustrated where I went wrong, and helped me fix my issue. I appreciate it!